# Istio 1.5.7 installation fails on kubernetes 1.18.6 with centos 7.8(3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64) with calico network CNI

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos7, istio

**I have installed fresh k8s 1.18.6 on multinode ( 12GB RAM & 4 CPU)  on centos-7.8(3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64) with docker version (19.03.6) & runc version 1.0.0-rc10.**

> I used calico(3.11.1) network plugin and till here everything worked
> fine. When i am trying to install istio 1.5.7 on it i am facing issue
> as below

Issue:

1. Detected that your cluster does not support third party JWT
   authentication. Falling back to less secure first party JWT.  See
   https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens
   for details.
2. error   installer       Failed to wait for resource: resources not
   ready after 10m0s: timed out waiting for the condition
   Deployment/istio-system/istiod

**kubectl get pods -n istio-system**
*NAME                                    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-5f6f8cbf75-lngb7                1/1     Running             0          41s
istio-egressgateway-cbd86567c-5x6rk     0/1     ContainerCreating   0          44s
istio-ingressgateway-799d5b8875-4ztq8   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          42s
istio-tracing-9dd6c4f7c-vv64n           1/1     Running             0          41s
istiod-b7d8f955b-mtqgb                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    5          10m
kiali-869c6894c5-pw7sm                  1/1     Running             0          41s
prometheus-7d697b95b-2rjvn              0/2     ContainerCreating   0          41s*

**istiod-pod-logs:**
info    No certificates specified, skipping DNS certificate controller
info    CRD controller watching namespaces ""
info    Ingress controller watching namespaces ""
warn    Config Store &{0xc00020c6c0 cluster.local 0xc00026b1e0 0xc000795e00 0xc00079eea0 []} cannot track distribution in aggregate
info    Adding Kubernetes registry adapter
info    Service controller watching namespace "" for services, endpoints, nodes and pods, refresh 1m0s
info    JWT policy is first-party-jwt
info    Use self-signed certificate as the CA certificate
info    pkica   Failed to get secret (error: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/secrets/istio-ca-secret: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout), will create one
Error: failed to create discovery service: enableCA: failed to create a self-signed Citadel: failed to create CA due to secret write error
error   pkica   Failed to write secret to CA (error: Post https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/secrets: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout). Abort.
error   failed to create discovery service: enableCA: failed to create a self-signed Citadel: failed to create CA due to secret write error

Comment: From what I see in the logs you provided your cluster does not support third party JWT authentication. Could you try with `--set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt` when you install istio? There is related part about that in istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens). Also worth to note that there is already istio version 1.8.2, consider installing the new version due to the improvements.

Comment: Hi Jakub,
Thank you for replying on my post.
I tried with the flag as you suggested but i am still failing with the same issue.
Its like this flag has no affect after adding it in command
I used it as below=
"istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt"

Comment: That's weird, is there a chance you could add 4GB of ram to your setup? If I remember correctly istio requires at least 16GB of ram, maybe it's just crushing because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Istio [v1.5 is out of support](https://istio.io/latest/news/support/announcing-1.5-eol-final/), as is [v1.6](https://istio.io/latest/news/support/announcing-1.6-eol-final/) and [v1.7 will soon be](https://istio.io/latest/news/support/announcing-1.7-eol/).

I also don't think v1.5 was ever approved for K8s v1.18.

My suggestion would be to use Istio v1.8 and to disable Calico before attempting to install.

Answer (score -1):

1. I would start with checking if your cluster supports third party tokens, more about it [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens).

> Because the properties of the first party token are less secure, Istio will default to using third party tokens. However, this feature is not enabled on all Kubernetes platforms.
>
> If you are using istioctl to install, support will be automatically detected. This can be done manually as well, and configured by passing --set values.global.jwtPolicy=third-party-jwt or --set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt.
>
> To determine if your cluster supports third party tokens, look for the TokenRequest API. If this returns no response, then the feature is not supported:

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1 | jq '.resources[] | select(.name | index("serviceaccounts/token"))'
{
    "name": "serviceaccounts/token",
    "singularName": "",
    "namespaced": true,
    "group": "authentication.k8s.io",
    "version": "v1",
    "kind": "TokenRequest",
    "verbs": [
        "create"
    ]
}
```

---

2. Then I would check the requirements, according to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/minikube/#installation-steps) you should have at least 16384 MB of memory and 4 CPUs to run istio.

There is another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373346/istioctl-install-fails-with-multiple-timeouts) case where community member had same problem with 12GB of RAM.

---

3. I would also check the versions, as mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/v1.5/pt-br/docs/setup/getting-started/#platform)

> Istio 1.5 has been tested with Kubernetes releases 1.14, 1.15, 1.16.

As you use **Kubernetes** 1.18.6 version, it might not work with **Istio** 1.5 version.

---

So I would recommend to go with this approach:

- Add 4GB of RAM to your cluster,
- Use newer version of istio,
- Install istio with `--set values.global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt`.